# display inline-block not working on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is this because of the inline block issue that safari not support ?

```css
input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
}

input::-webkit-search-decoration,
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}

#package-search input[type=search] {
  color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 56px;
  background: #fff url(assets/img/img/icon/search-b.png) no-repeat 30px 18px;
  background-size: 23px auto;
  border-radius: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#package-search input[type=search]:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}

#package-search input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 380px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #343434;
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: auto;
}

#package-search input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

#package-search input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

this button search has transitioned to get more width when we hover or click and it gonna block another div beside that button search icon

but on safari it doesn't block another div, the result that button box when we hover or click, it gonna be behind on that another div

what cause of this ? do I missing something?

look at this issue 
[look here and click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHg7V.png)